# Is it possible to run kubernetes in a shared AWS VPC private network, without dns hostnames enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, kube-dns

I trying to setup Kubernetes cluster using kops,
having all of my nodes and master running on a private shabnets on my existing AWS VPC,
when passing the vpcid and network cidr to the create command, i'm enforced to have the EnableDNSHostnames=true,
I wonder of it's possible to setup a cluster with that option set to false
So all of the instances lunched in the private vpc wont have public address 
Thanks

Comment: `EnableDNSHostnames=true` **does not** determine whether instances launched into VPC will have public IP addresses.  That isn't what this option controls.

Comment: You can fork kops and change that option in the code. Your cluster should work though a few tools will fail, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/399. I believe this might be better in Kubernetes 1.5.

Comment: Thanks @PixelElephant, Is that issue is related to kops, or to kubernetes in general ? (like issues like kubectl exec or kubectl logs don't work)
also what is the impact of setting up a cluster with associate-public-ip on master and nodes set to False
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's completely possible to run in private subnets, that's how I deploy my cluster (https://github.com/upmc-enterprises/kubernetes-on-aws), where all servers are in private subnets and access is granted via bastion boxes.

For kops specifically, looks like there's support (https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/428), but I'm not a big user of it so can't speak 100% to how well it works.